# $\tau(A) =\{ U_1 \cup ( U_2 \cap A) : U_1 , U_2 \in \tau \}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space  and $A \not\in \tau$ , then $\tau(A) =\{ U_1 \cup ( U_2 \cap A) : U_1 , U_2 \in \tau \}$ is topological space on $X$ generated by  the subbase $\{ A\} \cup \tau$.

> Is $( X, \tau ( X- A )$ is **compact ( countably compact)**, if $( X , \tau)$ and $A\subset X$ is **compact ( countably compact)**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let $\tau'=\tau(X\setminus A)$ where $A\subseteq X$ is (countably) compact, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ be a (countable) $\tau'$-open cover of $X$. For each $\alpha\in A$ there are $V_\alpha,W_\alpha\in\tau$ such that $$U_\alpha=V_\alpha\cup\big(W_\alpha\cap(X\setminus A)\big)=V_\alpha\cup(W_\alpha\setminus A)\;.$$ Clearly $\{V_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ is a $\tau$-open cover of $A$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq A$ such that $\{V_\alpha:\alpha\in F\}$ covers $A$. $\{V_\alpha\cup W_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ is a $\tau$-open cover of $X$ so there is a finite $F'\subseteq A$ such that $\{V_\alpha\cup W_\alpha:\alpha\in F'\}$ covers $X$. Let $F''=F\cup F'$; then on the one hand

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in F''}U_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in F''}\big(V_\alpha\cup(W_\alpha\setminus A)\big)\supseteq\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in F''}(V_\alpha\cup W_\alpha)\right)\setminus A=X\setminus A\;,$$

and on the other hand

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in F''}U_\alpha\supseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in F}V_\alpha\supseteq A\;,$$

so $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in F''\}$ covers $X$.